# How to install Sublime Text 2/3 with GLIBC 2.07 and without any access to root/admin rights?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, libc, kde-plasma

I want to install Sublime Text at school, but I haven't any access to root/admin rights. I tried to dowwnload the archive (tar.gz), unpack it and start Sublime, but it needs GLIBC_2.11 and we have 2.07. There is no possibility to update the libc.so library.
Is there any way to force Sublime Text to run with a newer version (maybe download it and unpack it in the directory)?
Would be awesome if someone has an idea...

We are running Linux KDE 32 bit...

Comment: Couldn't you obtain GLIBC_2.11, store it locally, and then do something like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/GLIBC_2.11"` prior to starting sublime?

Comment: Do I need root rights to call EXPORT? I'm not sure, but if I don't need it, it could be possible. I would download the needed software from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/ . Is is the right website?

Comment: export is a standard shell command in every unix shell.. nothing special there. You can probably grab glibc source code, compile it locally and then put LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing there.

Comment: Worked like a charm :D Thanks guys. The only problem was to compile glibc for 32 bit machines on my 64 bit Ubuntu. Took my some hours, but I finally did it

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you obtain `GLIBC_2.11`, store it locally, and then do something like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/GLIBC_2.11"
```

prior to starting sublime?